# automatic synchronisation on ubuntu (ftp/local)

Tags: ubuntu, sync, ftp

Is there a deamon/app for ubuntu which could monitor and sync my folder with ftp after editing a file there?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you rig up a script that's called as a cron job.

[Rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) is a classic epic tool for this kind of thing.

I don't think rsync will work over FTP though, so if you must be on FTP as in your question, then perhaps [take a look at this script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-autologin-cron-ftp-script/).